# Name [name] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc]

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, tomcat

Na expectativa de melhorar o desempenho ao acesso no BD eu comecei a implementar um pool de conexões dentro da minha Aplicação web. Porém sempre que vou dar um lookup na aplicação me ocorre o seguinte erro

> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/bolsa] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
>       at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:818)
>       at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:166)
>       at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:157)
>       at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
>       at Filtro.Filtro.doFilter(Filtro.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206
>       ....(continua)

Ao procura vários QeA e tutoriais eu acabei implementando os arquivos do `Tomcat` da seguinte maneira

*server.xml*

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="jdbc/bolsa" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000"
      username="root" password="" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
      url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bolsa"/>
</GlobalNamingResources>
```

*context.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/zk_login">
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <ResourceLink global="jdbc/bolsa" name="jdbc/bolsa" type="javax.sql.DataSource" />

    <Resource name="jdbc/bolsa" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000"
              username="root" password="" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bolsa"/>
</Context>
```

Já dentro do meu `sistema` eu o *persistence.xml* ficou da seguinte maneira

*persistence.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="bolsa" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
       <non-jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/bolsa</non-jta-data-source>
        <class>bean.Permissao</class>
        <class>bean.Usuario</class>
        <class>bean.Pagina</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>


        <properties>

            <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <!-- dados da conexao -->
            <!--  propriedades do hibernate -->
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

e o *web.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
         version="2.4">
    <description>MySQL Test App</description>
    <resource-ref>
        <description>DB Connection</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/bolsa</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

Como posso configurar o meu servidor ou se estou minha chamada esta errada e como posso solucionar esse problema.

Infelizmente eu ja olhei vários tutoriais e video mas nenhum dele funcionou :/

Comment: Se você tirar a tag `<Resource ..... />` do context.xml não funciona?

Comment: Infelizmente acontece o mesmo erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu solucionei o meu problema e tive que resolver vários outros problemas juntos. Então irei mostra a solução de todos passo a passo.

## Mudança de versão do Hibernate

Eu estava usando a versão `hibernate-core-4.3.0` e `hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.0`. Porém como meu objetivo era usar Pool de conexão, tive que atualizar a versão do hibernate já que estas haviam problemas para implementar o Data Source.

Com isso mudei para a versão `hibernate-core-5.2.11` e `hibernate-entitymanager-5.2.11`. Com isso alguns comandos foram modificados.
A biblioteca `ejb` se tornou *decrepated* (ultrapassada) a partir da versão 4.3, então tiver que usar a biblioteca `jpa` como visto nesse [post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/247447/no-persistence-provider-for-entitymanager-para-o-hibernate-5-x)

O `Provider` também modificou e passou de `HibernatePersistence` para `HibernatePersistenceProvider`.

De modo que `persistence.xml` ficou da seguinte maneira:

```
<persistence-unit name="bolsa" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/bolsa</non-jta-data-source>
    ...
</persistence-unit>
```

## Pool de conexão (DataSource) usando Tomcat

Apesar de eu ter modificado muito arquivo do `Tomcat`, o único que era necessário era o `context.xml`, que ficou:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context >
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <!-- <ResourceLink global="jdbc/bolsa" name="jdbc/bolsa" type="javax.sql.DataSource" /> -->

    <Resource name="jdbc/bolsa" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000"
              username="root" password="" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bolsa"/>
</Context>
```

Com isso eu consigo capturar o Data source atraves do comando:

```
<non-jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/bolsa</non-jta-data-source>
```

Só não esqueça de colocar `java:comp/env/` antes do ome do DataSource.