# "No Persistence provider for EntityManager" para o Hibernate 5.x

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistência

Bom, tiver que atualizar a versão do `hibernate` que estava já que quero implementar no meu projeto pra evitar bugs da versão passadas, porém estou com dificuldade de fazer a persistência na nova versão, já que houve mudanças.

A primeira foi o `Provider` que agora é feito pela classe `HibernatePersistenceProvider`. Com isso meu `persistence.xml` ficou da seguinte maneira:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="bolsa" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>bean.Permissao</class>
        <class>bean.Usuario</class>
        <class>bean.Pagina</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <!-- dados da conexao -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bolsa" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
            <!--  propriedades do hibernate -->
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Tento capturar a unidade de persistencia de acordo com a [documentação](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#bootstrap-native) do hibernate e minha captura ficou da seguinte maneira:

```java
@PersistenceUnit
private final EntityManagerFactory factory;
private final EntityManager manager;

public __constructor() {
    this.factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("bolsa");
    this.manager = factory.createEntityManager();
}
```

Porém, mesmo assim continua dando o seguinte erro:

> ```
> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named bolsa
>     at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:61)
>     at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
>     at dao.Manager.<init>(Manager.java:36)
>     at dao.Manager.create(Manager.java:28)
>     at dao.Manager.create(Manager.java:24)
>     at Service.AbstractService.execGet(AbstractService.java:47)
>     at Service.AbstractService.get(AbstractService.java:77)
>     at Filtro.Filtro.doFilter(Filtro.java:72)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>     at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> ```

A configuração do meu POM.xml com os arquivos do hibernate ficou:

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.11.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.11.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.11.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

e a configuração dos meu arquivo ficou:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: `private __constructor()`?

Comment: eu modifiquei pra `public` para melhor entendimento, mas isso era pelo método de implementação de construtor, onde eu só chama na classe. Mas creio que isso não interfere, pois o método é chamado.

Comment: O problema não é o `private` ou `public`. O problema é que `__constructor` não é algo que exista em Java. No Java, o construtor sempre tem o mesmo nome da classe, senão você vai ter um erro de compilação.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Hibernate 5.2 o *persistence provider* padrão é o [`org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/jpa/HibernatePersistenceProvider.html). O [*provider* no pacote ejb](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/ejb/HibernateEntityManager.html) já estava sendo *deprecated* desde a versão 4.3 do Hibernate ORM.

Mude a linha do `provider` no `persistence.xml` para:

```
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
```

E tudo deve funcionar.

---

**Fonte**: [SOen - Hibernate 5.2.2: No Persistence provider for EntityManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410183/hibernate-5-2-2-no-persistence-provider-for-entitymanager)