# Migração do Hibernate 4.3.x para 5.3.1

Tags: hibernate, maven

Estou fazendo um curso de Sistema de Vendas, o professor utiliza a versão `4.3.11` do `Hibernate`(o que funciona perfeitamente).

Porém gostaria de `migrar` para a versão atual(`5.3.1`), porém com a configuração da versão passada, aquela dada no curso, não é possível fazer a persistência no banco de dados.

Esse é o código do arquivo **hibernate.cfg.xml** (versão `4.3.11`, que está funcionando):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd"><hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Configurações da conexão com o Banco -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vendas?useTimezone=true&amp;serverTimezone=UTC</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">xxxxx</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</property>

        <!-- Config da conexao JDBC Mysql -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>

        <!-- Gerenciamento da sessão mysql -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Desabilita o cache -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Exibe os comando SQL -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Criação das tabelas -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <mapping class="br.com.livraria.domain.Fornecedores" />
        <mapping class="br.com.livraria.domain.Funcionarios" />

        <!-- <mapping class="br.com.livraria.domain.Produtos" /> 
        <mapping class="br.com.livraria.domain.Vendas" /> 
        <mapping class="br.com.livraria.domain.Item" /> -->

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Classe HibernateUtil.java**:

package br.com.livraria.util;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

public class HibernateUtil {

```
private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {
        // Cria uma conexão a partir do hibernate.cfg.xml

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();

        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();


        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

        return sessionFactory;

        //return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory(
          //  new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().build() );
    }
    catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Mensagem de erro ao conectar
        System.err.println("Erro na conexão." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}
public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}}
```

Resultado do **console** quando altero a versão do Hibernate para 5.3.1.FINAL:

```
jun 02, 2018 7:06:38 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.1.Final}

jun 02, 2018 7:06:38 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found

jun 02, 2018 7:06:39 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.3.Final}

jun 02, 2018 7:06:40 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)

jun 02, 2018 7:06:40 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vendas?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC]

jun 02, 2018 7:06:40 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}

jun 02, 2018 7:06:40 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false

jun 02, 2018 7:06:40 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)

Sat Jun 02 19:06:40 BRT 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.

jun 02, 2018 7:06:40 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

jun 02, 2018 7:06:40 PM org.hibernate.resource.beans.spi.ManagedBeanRegistryInitiator resoveBeanContainer
INFO: HHH10005002: No explicit CDI BeanManager reference was passed to Hibernate, but CDI is available on the Hibernate ClassLoader.

jun 02, 2018 7:06:41 PM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@3f6db3fb] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.

jun 02, 2018 7:06:41 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl stop
INFO: HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool[jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vendas?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC]
```

Acredito que o problema esteja no item `jun 02, 2018 7:06:41 PM` mas não consegui identificar uma solução.
Estou usando o `Eclipse`, `MAVEN`, `JSF` e `JUnit`.

Comment: Eu também tive problema com migração. No caso eu não usei o arquivo "HIBERNATE.CFG.XML"
Creio que o erro esteja na PERSISTENCE.XML, de uma olhada em um post que fiz recentemente, acho deve ajudar 
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/247447/no-persistence-provider-for-entitymanager-para-o-hibernate-5-x

Answer (score 2):

Dar uma lida em: 
http://www.thejavageek.com/jpa-tutorials/

Mas um exemplo bem simples seria:

Arquivo **persistence.xml**

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
         version="2.1">

<persistence-unit name="PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <description> Hibernate JPA Configuration Example</description>
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" /> <!-- DB Driver ALTERE-->
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://172.17.0.2/academy" /> <!-- BD ALTERE -->
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres" /> <!-- DB User -->
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="123456" /> <!-- DB Password -->

        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgresPlusDialect"/> <!-- Altere pro mysql -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" /> <!-- create / create-drop / update -->

        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" /> <!-- Show SQL in console -->
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" /> <!-- Show SQL formatted -->
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Arquivo **Pessoa.java**

```
@Entity 
public class Pessoa {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String nome;

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String name) {
        this.nome = name;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Pessoa(String nome, Long id) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Pessoa(String nome){
        this(nome,null);
    }

    public Pessoa(){}

}
```

Arquivo Main.java

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class Main {
    private static EntityManager em;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence
            .createEntityManagerFactory("PU");
     em = emf.createEntityManager();
     em.getTransaction().begin();
     em.persist(new Pessoa("NOMEQUALQUER"));
     em.getTransaction().commit();
   }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Mas não resolveu o problema, estou utilizando o Hibernate puro. Não possuo o persistence.xml  e quando o incluo (ficando com os dois hibernate.cfg.xml e persistence.xml, esse último não é lido) e se deixo somente o persistence.xml o Hibernate reclama da falta do cfg.xml.

Answer (score 1):

À partir de não sei que versão o Hibernate passou ir cada vez mais em direção à especificação JPA e eles recomendam fortemente essa forma de trabalho a partir de agora.

Algumas coisas como o Criteria, HibernateEntityManager, por exemplo, já estão deprecated e logo logo vão sumir do framework ou não ter mais manutenção.

Não sei o tamanho do seu projeto, mas se você quiser ir para o 5.3.1 é interessante dar uma estudada sobre JPA e migrá-lo. A mudança não é simples, mas recomendada para trabalhar com as versões mais novas do Hibernate. Fiz isso aqui e deu um pouco de trabalho por conta do tamanho dos projetos, mas no final tudo funcionou.